# SBT: How to Dockerize a fat jar?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-native-packager

I'm building a Docker image with a fat jar. I use the `sbt-assembly` plugin to build the jar, and the `sbt-native-packager` to build the Docker image. I'm not very familiar with SBT and am running into the following issues.

1. I'd like to declare a dependency on the `assembly` task from the `docker:publish` task, such that the fat jar is created before it's added to the image. I did as instructed in the [doc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html#Migrating+when+using+%2C++or), but it's not working. `assembly` doesn't run until I invoke it.

   `publish := (publish dependsOn assembly).value`
2. One of the steps in building the image is copying the fat jar. Since assembly plugin creates the jar in `target/scala_whatever/projectname-assembly-X.X.X.jar`, I need to know the exact `scala_whatever` and the jar name. assembly seems to have a key `assemblyJarName` but I'm not sure how to access it. I tried the following which fails.

   `Cmd("COPY", "target/scala*/*.jar /app.jar")`

Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own questions, the following works:

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x => {
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    val strategy = oldStrategy(x)
    if (strategy == MergeStrategy.deduplicate)
      MergeStrategy.first
    else strategy
  }
}

// Remove all jar mappings in universal and append the fat jar
mappings in Universal := {
  val universalMappings = (mappings in Universal).value
  val fatJar = (assembly in Compile).value
  val filtered = universalMappings.filter {
    case (file, name) => !name.endsWith(".jar")
  }
  filtered :+ (fatJar -> ("lib/" + fatJar.getName))
}

dockerRepository := Some("username")

import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.{Cmd, ExecCmd}
dockerCommands := Seq(
  Cmd("FROM", "username/spark:2.1.0"),
  Cmd("WORKDIR", "/"),
  Cmd("COPY", "opt/docker/lib/*.jar", "/app.jar"),
  ExecCmd("ENTRYPOINT", "/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit", "/app.jar")
)
```

I completely overwrite the docker commands because the defaults add couple of scripts that I don't need because I overwrite the entrypoint as well. Also, the default workdir is `/opt/docker` which is not where I want to put the fat jar. 
Note that the default commands are shown by `show dockerCommands` in sbt console.

Comment: Yep. This is the example from the documentation. A small hint: You can remove the `DockerPlugin` in `enablePlugins(...)`. The `JavaAppPackaging` enables it by default.

Comment: @Muki Not exactly from the doc. The doc uses deprecated `jarName` and doesn't have an example of fat jar as a Docker container, but only individual pieces. But yes, I got the idea from the doc.
Can you say if there's a way to stop generating the scripts that serve as default entrypoint? I don't include them but they still get generated in `opt/docker/bin` locally.